# Retaining login info using lightopenid / logging out

Tags: php, codeigniter, lightopenid

Using the example code provided I've made it possible to log in to my app using my Google account via lightopenid. I have stored the identity in a cookie so that my login can persist across the session.

How do I then revalidate this ID to keep them logged in as the user navigates my site? I want to keep their name displayed in the top right corner / respond to them logging out.

Creating a new lightopenid object, setting the identity and calling validate() doesn't work - my lightopenid object is an array with not much in it, and validate() returns false.

Further to this, how would I code a link enabling the user to log out?

Login code (which is working to get the user IN to my site):

```
    $openID = new LightOpenID($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    $openID -> required = array(
        'namePerson',
        'namePerson/first',
        'namePerson/last',
        'contact/email'
    );

    if (!$openID -> mode) {
        // TRYING TO LOG IN
        $openID -> identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
        redirect($openID -> authUrl());
    } else {            
        $page_data = array(
            "page_title"     => "Login",
            "additional_css" => array(),
            "additional_js"  => array()
        );

        if ($openID -> mode == "cancel") {
            $login_error = array(
                "login_error" => "Google authentication cancelled"
            );

            $this -> load -> view('global/header',$page_data);  
            $this -> load -> view('login/form',$login_error);
            $this -> load -> view('global/footer'); 
        } else {
            if ($openID -> validate()) {
                $openID_identity = $openID -> identity;
                $openID_data     = $openID -> getAttributes();
                $first_name      = $openID_data["namePerson/first"];
                $last_name       = $openID_data["namePerson/last"];
                $email           = $openID_data["contact/email"];

                $login = array(
                    "first_name" => $first_name,
                    "last_name"  => $last_name
                );

                // SESSION COOKIE
                $this -> session -> set_userdata(array(
                    "user_id"    => 0,
                    "identity"   => $openID_identity,
                    "first_name" => $first_name,
                    "last_name"  => $last_name,
                    "email"      => $email
                ));

                redirect("/login/welcome");
            } else {
                $login_error = array(
                    "login_error" => "Google authentication failed"
                );

                $this -> load -> view('global/header',$page_data);  
                $this -> load -> view('login/form',$login_error);
                $this -> load -> view('global/footer'); 
            }
        }           
    }
```

Comment: Your code looks like a bunch of text... maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Bunch of text edited to add wall of text.

Comment: Ah! Much better :) I haven't used OA, but from a cursory look at their docs, it appears Smart mode is required to persists authentication, and Lightopenid only has "dumb" mode. However, if all you want is to track auth, maybe use db sessions and check for the openID identity. Use the db cookie for username and delete the cookie on logout.

Comment: @stormdrain: smart mode has nothing to do with persistence. The only better thing about it is that it uses one less request for authentication.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a session mechanism (like php sessions). That way, you don't have to verify the identity again.

Generally, in order to verify the identifier again, you'd have to repeat the whole authentication process, which isn't a good idea.

You can't log an user out of openid. You can, however, delete your session, so that your server doesn't remember that this user is logged in anymore (which is exactly the same thing you would do if not using openid).

Also, please read the documentation attached at the top of `openid.php`:

```
 * Change the 'my-host.example.org' to your domain name. Do NOT use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
 * for that, unless you know what you are doing.
```

Of course, that is, unless you really understand the security implications of using it.

Comment: CodeIgniter has built in classes for sessions (db-based or otherwise) which might make more sense than the native PHP sessions in this case since the library is available. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html